# Automatically Add name="blah" tag to nth <td> in a <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with many `<tr>` each containing multiple `<td>`.

I want to automatically add name="blah" tags to each `<td>` in the row via CSS or JavaScript.

So in effect, each `<td>` will go from:

```
<tr>
<td>Col 1 Text</td>
<td>Col 2 Text</td>
<td>Col 3 Text</td>
</tr>
```

To:

```
<tr>
<td name="col1">Col 1 Text</td>
<td name="col2">Col 2 Text</td>
<td name="col3">Col 3 Text</td>
</tr>
```

I need to do this because I have some JavaScript that formats the cells according to their contents, and that searches for the cells by the `<td>` name.

Any ideas how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: At the moment, I'm manually adding the tags to each <td> but this fails when people use the CMS to add new rows to the table, as these tags won't be automatically added.

Comment: Thjis is called an attribute, not a tag. `<td>` is a tag. Note that `name` attribute [isn't standard to this tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) though. You might want to elaborate a bit more on the final goal you're trying to achieve as I have the ffeling you may be going a wrong direction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setAttribute()`

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].setAttribute('name', 'col' + (i + 1));
}
```

```css
td[name]{
  background:green;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1 Text</td>
    <td>Col 2 Text</td>
    <td>Col 3 Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great, but only on the first row in the table.

Comment: @finisterre,  it should work on all cells. Can you reproduce the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @finisterre, here is the fixed version http://jsfiddle.net/tdwt1rqf/5/  what was happening is the second row had col4 and col6 so you have to iterate by row rather than **all** td elements

Comment: Superb. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].setAttribute("name", "col" + i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want this style

```
<tr>
    <td name="col1"></td>
    <td name="col2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td name="col1"></td>
    <td name="col2"></td>
</tr>
```

apply this JS

```
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i=0; i<tr.length; ++i) {
    var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for(vat j=0; j<td.length; ++j) {
        td[j].setAttribute("name","col"+(j+1));
    }
}
```

if you want this style

```
<tr>
    <td name="col1"></td>
    <td name="col2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td name="col3"></td>
    <td name="co42"></td>
</tr>
```

apply this JS

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i=0; i<td.length; ++i) {
    td[i].setAttribute("name","col"+(i+1));
}
```